# Why OpenGL state changes very slow on VirtualBox?

Tags: opengl, virtualbox

I'm on Linux host and using a Windows guest.

I'm creating the OpenGL context with SDL, and I just draw 1000 objects in different positions, each object is just 6 vertices and 3 lines, just a 3D cross.

I'm using vertex and index buffers and GLSL shaders. It doesn't do anything special: it binds the buffers and sets the vertex attrib pointers, set the matrix and draws the elements.

It renders the scene in 2 seconds, if I hoist the buffer binding and attribute setting outside the loop it renders in 200ms, if I remove glUniformMatrix4fv that sets the matrix due to the updated positions it'll render about 10ms, though I only see 1 object and thousand other is just overdrawn on it.

On Linux and Windows host the same thing renders on stable 60FPS.

OpenGL games like OpenArena run on 60FPS in VirtualBox...

Is buffer binding and uniform setting a slow operation in OpenGL in general?

Does anyone has experience testing 3D programs on VirtualBox?

Update: added some code, error checking removed for clarity:

```
void drawStuff()
{
    GLfloat projectView[16];
    int ms;
    RenderingContext rc; /*< Nothing special contains the currently bound render object.*/

    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    createViewMatrix(
        viewMatrix,
        &viewedObject->attitude.k,
        &viewedObject->attitude.j,
        &viewedObject->pos
    );

    multiplyMatrix(projectView, viewMatrix, projMatrix); /*< Combine projection and view matrices. */

    /* Draw 10×10×10 grid of 3D crosses. One cross is 6 vertices and 3 lines. */
    bindRenderObject(&rc, &cross); /*< This binds buffers and sets up vertex attrib arrays. It's very slow if I put it into the loop*/
    {
        int i, j, k;
        for (i = -5; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for (j = -5; j < 5; j++)
            {
                for (k = -5; k < 5; k++)
                {
                    createTranslationMatrix(modelMatrix, i * 10, j * 10, k * 10);

                    multiplyMatrix(combinedMatrix, modelMatrix, projectView);
                    glUniformMatrix4fv(renderingMatrixId, 1, GL_FALSE, combinedMatrix); /*< This is slow for some reason.*/

                    drawRenderObject(&rc); /*< This is just a call to glDrawElements. No performance bottleneck here at all. */
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /* Draw some UI. */
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    /* ... */

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();
}
```

Comment: It is hard to say without seeing any code. But if you are doing something like querying uniform locations by name every time you set them, then this could be a major part of the reason. Uniform locations do not change until you re-link a GLSL program, so you can find them by name (**string**) once and then store the **integer** location persistently. String search functions are notoriously expensive, and OpenGL does not require an implementation to be smart and optimize them using something like a trie; thus you should always assume that your implementation is dumb as a brick.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I don't query uniform location by name, I saved the returned ID and use it only. Added some code.

Comment: 1000 draw calls for this purpose is actually a little excessive. I assume that since you are using VirtualBox, you are not actually exposed to a hardware OpenGL implementation (e.g. you're stuck with Mesa)... but this is a good use-case for instancing. You can transfer your array of 1,000 uniforms as a UBO and eliminate the need to break this up into 1,000 separate draw calls. Even in a software implementation that will probably give you a performance gain.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman VirtualBox's OpenGL support is pretty limited, it supports OpenGL 2.0 barely. So it has buffers but doesn't have eg. vertex array objects. I don't think it supports UBO.

Comment: VirtualBox does not implement OpenGL. Something else installed on your system does, likely Mesa. Newer versions of Mesa support (partially, anyway) up to OpenGL 3.3.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman The **host is Linux**, the **guest is Windows**, and VirtualBox guest additions must install at least some kind of OpenGL driver into Windows to send drawing commands from guest to host. I don't think software rendering can run OpenArena on 60FPS.

Mesa runs on host... Is it possible to get OpenGL 3 on Windows by installing something into the guest? Is extensions come from the driver? GLEW returns NULL pointers on many v3 functions.